# Error al conectarse a la DB de mongo

Tags: javascript, nodejs, express

Estoy queriendo conectarme a una base de datos de mongoose(web), y me tira listen EADDRINUSE: address already in use :::4000. Tengo una api que escucha el puerto 4000 pero dentro de la funcion de mongoose no la utilizo

```
module.exports = ()=>
{
    const connect = ()=>{
        mongoose.connect(
            URL,
            {
                keepAlive:true,
                userNewUrlParser:true,
                useUnifiedTopology:true
            },
            (error)=>{
                if(error){
                    console.log('Error al conectar la DB ',error)
                }else{
                    console.log('Conexion exitosa')
                }
            }
        )
    }
    connect()
};
```

[image: Error obtenido al conectar]

Comment: Hola Alan, no es necesario utilizarla dentro de ese código para que de error. Un puerto sólo puede estar en uso por un servicio. Tendrás que modificar el puerto de uno de los dos.

Comment: Buenas, dentro de la funcion de conexion no utilizo nada con respecto al puerto, ese puerto lo estaba utilizando para ejecutar un servicio.

Comment: Sí, pero no importa. Aunque el servicio no tenga nada que ver con la web o incluso si es un videojuego, si está utilizando el puerto, ese puerto no podrá ser utilizado por nada más. Asegúrate de que el servicio está completamente cerrado y vuelve a intentarlo o cambia el puerto de uno de los servicios.

Comment: Como puedo cambiarle el puerto a la base de datos, porque no le setee ninguna